# Program to log when windows are moved to another monitor

Tags: display, logs

I am looking for a program - ideally free and supporting Windows 7 - to log whenever windows are moved to another monitor. E.g. the log would be something like:

```
Datetime, application name, monitor source, monitor destination
2014-04-25 01:02, Google Chrome, Monitor 1, Monitor 3
2014-04-25 01:05, Microsoft PowerPoint, Monitor 4, Monitor 2
etc
```

If possible, it would also record when a monitor is disabled or enabled, as well as when a window is minimized, reduced or maximized.

Purpose:

- better understand how windows are shuffled around my laptop goes to sleep
- self-quantification and productivity analysis: e.g. optimize the way I move windows around by spotting inefficient/useless moves in the log
- spot weird behavior: e.g. a window gets minimized in a monitor, and when I reopen it it appears in another monitor.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically incomplete answer at the moment but it might give you a clue:

[AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) macros can handle `EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND` event produced by other windows after their moving/sizing finished. This should give you access to current data of the window so you can log it. [More information is here.](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/32662-tool-wineventhook-messages/) This might need more R&D to create the macro, this answer is attempt to show you a direction.

[For details of AutoHotKey setup see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22880354/2392157) covering different scenario of AutoHotKey usage.